# Java & Tomcat: Severe Error starting obfuscated app w/ hibernate inside

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, obfuscation, war

This is a little hard to explain..

I am using tomcat 6.0 to test deploy a WAR file. I'm using proGuard to obfuscate the WAR file.

To use proGuard, all the com.*, org.* etc that would normally be in WEB-INF/classes have to be packed into a single .jar in WEB-INF/lib.

Fine so far.

The problem comes when I deploy. The app uses Hibernate and a hibernate listener. This listener is failing to load. From this I gather that the .jar with the complete set of classes has been found and at least started to be utilised. The failing of the hibernate listener, however, ends the deployment of the app and nothing comes up, not even the index page.

My log file (set to DEBUG) gives me:

```
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [1381 prunsrv.c] [debug] Commons Daemon procrun log initialized
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [info] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.2.0) started
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [info] Running Service...
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [1165 prunsrv.c] [debug] Inside ServiceMain...
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [info] Starting service...
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[0] -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat\Tomcat 6.0
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[1] -Dcatalina.base=C:\tomcat\Tomcat 6.0
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[2] -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\tomcat\Tomcat 6.0\endorsed
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[3] -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\tomcat\Tomcat 6.0\temp
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[4] -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[5] -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\tomcat\Tomcat 6.0\conf\logging.properties
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[6] -Djava.class.path=C:\tomcat\Tomcat 6.0\bin\bootstrap.jar
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[7] vfprintf
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [629  javajni.c] [debug] argv[0] = start
[2011-11-11 10:19:33] [655  javajni.c] [debug] Java Worker thread started org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap:main
[2011-11-11 10:19:34] [1006 prunsrv.c] [debug] Java started org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap
[2011-11-11 10:19:34] [info] Service started in 1138 ms.
[2011-11-11 10:19:34] [1272 prunsrv.c] [debug] Waiting worker to finish...
```

and then stops.

Catalina gives me:

```
11-Nov-2011 10:21:35 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Does anyone have experience with getting hibernate to run inside an obfuscatable war (war is not actually obfuscated yet, it's just set up in the format proGuard needs it to be in in order to obfuscate), an independent jar, or even just how to get more precise logging!

Thanks

UPDATE:
I thought that Tomcat was finding the jar where the com.* classes etc. are, but now I am unsure. Does anyone know how to use the web.xml to point inside a specific .jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Currently it is, for example:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.*etc*.HibernateListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Application Name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>

etc etc...
```

but all these paths need to point inside a .jar file. Or else a property in the web.xml needs to define where these paths can be found.

Thanks

Comment: listenerStart doesn't mean the listener isn't found.  Instead it means that the listener is throwing an exception while loading.  Your logging isn't showing any org.hibernate logging?  Could you setup your logging to show everything?  I suspect an error is getting missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

For anyone having the same problem: I got the logging working finally using the logging.properties file in `WEB-INF/classes`. i put in settings found in many forum posts for just this eventuality. The main setting was DEBUG to catch the greatest detail.

This logging let me see that there was a jar missing, I had previously put it in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, but the app wan't seeing it so I had to put the class in the `/src/` folder and recompile. It worked anyway.

I am still having major problems with other elements of WAR obfuscation, but those are for other questions.

-S